# XPath to select element based on childs child value

Tags: xml, xpath

Trying to select an element based on the value of one of it's childrens childrens

Thinking the following but not working, appreciate any help, thanks

`./book[/author/name = 'John']` or

```
./book[/author/name text() = 'John']
```

Want all books where the author name = 'John'

Xml file

```
<list>
   <book>
      <author>
         <name>John</name>
         <number>4324234</number>
      </author>
      <title>New Book</title>
      <isbn>dsdaassda</isbn>
   </book>
   <book>...</book>
   <book>...</book>
</list>
```

Answer (score 368, accepted):

Almost there. In your predicate, you want a *relative* path, so change

```
./book[/author/name = 'John']
```

to either

```
./book[author/name = 'John']
```

or

```
./book[./author/name = 'John']
```

and you will match your element. Your current predicate goes back to the root of the document to look for an `author`.

Comment: Without `.` didn't work for me (needed `./author/name`)

Comment: Is it possible to use this syntax in a function? Eg, how to implement something such as `./book[contains(author/name, "John")]`?

Comment: @OgrishMan new questions should go in [New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), but before that I'd just try it! Generally you want single quotes `'` rather than double quotes `"` for string literals in xpath, by the way.