# xpath select parent based on child value

Tags: xml, xpath

I am looking to select every event where the status is "Live"

I am using this in Drupal's XPath XML parser and have the Context base query and xpath queries fields.

(Context=This is the base query, all other queries will run in this context.)

I current have:

Context:  `./event[./status = 'Live']`

title: `title`

Description: `description`

```
<events>

<event>
 <title>Number 1</title>
 <status>Draft</status>
 <description></description>
</event>

<event>
 <title>Number 1</title>
 <status>Live</status>
 <description></description>
</event>

</events>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [XPath to select element based on childs child value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683054/xpath-to-select-element-based-on-childs-child-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know drupal but this XPath worked fine for me in XPath tester :

```
./events/event[ status = 'Live']
```