# Xpath Value based on Child Node

Tags: xslt, xpath

From the below xml,i need an xpath to take the id value only when the state is FL.

Please help

```
<Employee_Details>
<Payroll>
    <id>A1</id>
    <City>Dallas</City>
    <State>TX</State>
</Payroll>
<Payroll>
    <id>A2</id>
    <City>Orlando</City>
    <State>FL</State>
</Payroll>
```

Comment: Unless you have tried something and failed, this is duplicate of [xpath select parent based on child value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898248/xpath-select-parent-based-on-child-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"i need an xpath to take the id value only when the state is FL"*

That can be translated into the following XPath expression :

```
/Employee_Details/Payroll[State='FL']/id
```

maybe you want to append `/text()` at the end to return the text node inside `<id>` element instead of the element itself.