# XPath selection by value

Tags: html, xpath

I want to get a value of "square" (for example, 201). I tried to do so, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683054/xpath-to-select-element-based-on-childs-child-value), but it doesn't work:

```
./li[attributeTitle='Этаж']
```

Html code:

```
<div class = "A">
    <ui class = "B">
        <li>
            <span class = "attributeTitle"> Floor </span>
            <span class = "attributeValue"> 3 </span>
        </li>
        <! A random more items "li" >
        <li>
            <span class = "attributeTitle"> Square </span>
            <span class = "attributeValue"> 201 </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class = "attributeTitle"> Nrooms </span>
            <span class = "attributeValue"> 4 </span>
        </li>
    </ui>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How is it working? What do you expect and what do you see instead?

Comment: Please show a complete, but minimal, input HTML document. Thanks. More help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `contains()` function in xpath to check whether text contains some string:

```
"//div[@class='attributeTitle'][contains(text(),'Square')]"
```

This gets you this node:

```
<span class = "attributeTitle"> Square </span>
```

To get the value node that is right below it you can use `following-sibling::span`:

```
"//div[@class='attributeTitle'][contains(text(),'Square')]/following-sibling::span[1]"
```

And adding `[1]` to indicate that we want only the first sibling in case there are more than one sibling. You can also use `[class='attributeValue']` instead to indicate that we only want siblings that have this particular class, or not use anything at all there if you trust there will only be 1 sibling.

Comment: `//div[@class='attributeTitle' and contains(text(),'Square')]` also works

Comment: also if what you posted is the complete DOM, then you don't need the [1] when getting the value since there is only one span node after the square element..