# XPath to select element based on child value

Tags: xslt, xpath

Trying to select an element based on the value of one of it's childrens

Im trying to do the same but it doesnt work.

XML:

```
    <customize>
      <name>InstallationZeitfenster</name>
      <dataType rvcd="2">Alphanumerisch</dataType>
      <value>Nachmittag</value>
    </customize>
    <customize>
      <name>InstallationGeplant</name>
      <dataType rvcd="3">Datum</dataType>
      <value>06.11.2019</value>
    </customize>
  </customize>
```

I want the text of the "value" node, with the node name = "InstallationGeplant" in it. Thats what i tried to do.

```
<xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='deviceManagement']/*[local-name()='deviceLocation']/*[local-name()='deviceInstallation']/*[local-name()='deviceInfo']/*[local-name()='device']/*[local-name()='customize']/*[local-name()='customize']/*[local-name()='name']/text() = 'InstallationGeplant'/*[local-name()='value']"/>
```

Has anyone some idea what i should do?

I have to access like this in to the nodes because of the namespaces.
Thanks for the help

Comment: I saw, that on this one is something similar, but not exactly like i did it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683054/xpath-to-select-element-based-on-childs-child-value/59192767#59192767

Answer (score 0):

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="descendant::value[preceding-sibling::name[1]='InstallationGeplant']"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do simply:

```
<xsl:value-of select="customize[name='InstallationGeplant']/value"/>
```

This is from the context of the parent `customize`; your attempt suggests that the structure is deeper than what you show.

---

> have to access like this in to the nodes because of the namespaces

No, you do not have to and should not. See: [XSLT Transform doesn't work until I remove root node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758492/xslt-transform-doesnt-work-until-i-remove-root-node/34762628#34762628)