# Applying templates to an element whose sibling element has a certain attribute value

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am trying to apply a template using XSLT1 and I can't get it to work:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[1]/SpecialEvent/Event[/Date[@AllDayEvent='1']]" mode="FirstRow_Pray">
    <xsl:with-param name="strClass">cellBold borderRight</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

I am trying to apply this template:

```
  <!--This is used to insert the Chairman, or Special Event-->
  <xsl:template match="Chairman | Event" mode="FirstRow_Pray">
    <xsl:param name="strClass"/>
    <td class="{$strClass}">
      <xsl:if test="self::Event">
        <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">2</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
```

But I only want to apply the template if the `Event` element exists and the **sibling** `Date[@AllDayEvent]` is true.

- I know I can wrap my `apply-templates` call with `if` clause first and that would work(see below).
- I know I can improve the logic of the `Event` template to test the value of the sibling elements attribute.

I have a lot of templates for using specific `Event` properties and would prefer the ability the select the item `Event` where its sibling element `Date` has a certain attribute value.

But my attempt does not work. I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683054/xpath-to-select-element-based-on-childs-child-value) and tried:

`MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[1]/SpecialEvent/Event[Date[@AllDayEvent='1']]`

But it still doesn't work.

---

This will work:

```
  <xsl:if test="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[1]/SpecialEvent/Date[@AllDayEvent='1']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[1]/SpecialEvent/Event" mode="FirstRow_Pray">
      <xsl:with-param name="strClass">cellBold borderRight</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:if>
```

But I want to avoid needing the `if` if possible.

I can now see what was wrong with my original attempt. `Date` is not a child of `Event` but a **sibling**.

- `MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[1]/SpecialEvent/Date`
- `MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[1]/SpecialEvent/Event`

So is it possible to apply a template on `Event` where the sibling `Date` has an attribute `AllDayEvent` with a value of `1`. Or do I have no choice but to use the `if` approach?

Sample XML data:

```
<Meeting BookmarkId="2" PageBreak="0" NumberClasses="1" SpecialEvent="1" CircuitVisit="0">
    <Date ThisWeek="W20200217" NextWeek="W20200224">February 17-23</Date>
    <WeeklyBibleReading>GENESIS 18-19</WeeklyBibleReading>
    <ReviewQuestion></ReviewQuestion>
    <SpecialEvent>
        <Event>Circuit Assembly - Love Jehovah With All Your Heart</Event>
        <Location>Bristol Assembly Hall, Hortham Lane, Bristol, BS32 4JH</Location>
        <Date Day="23" DayShort="Sun" DayFull="Sunday" Month="2" MonthShort="Feb" MonthFull="February" Year="2020" Memorial="0" AllDayEvent="1" MidweekEvent="1">23/02/2020</Date>
    </SpecialEvent>
</Meeting>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add the predicate to `SpecialEvent` instead of `Event`...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[1]/SpecialEvent[Date/@AllDayEvent='1']/Event" mode="FirstRow_Pray">
    <xsl:with-param name="strClass">cellBold borderRight</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```