# Select element based on childs child value

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to figure this out in [Whitebeam's testbed](http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm) based on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683054/xpath-to-select-element-based-on-childs-child-value) but i just can't get it to work.
I'm trying to select the "pet" element that has a "description" child with a "Large dog!" value.

This is my best bet but it doesn't work and i don't get why:

```
./pet[./description = 'Large dog!']
```

And here is the testbed's XML in case you dont want to open the link above.

```
<documentRoot>
<!-- Test data -->
<?value="2"?>
<parent name="data" >
   <child id="1"  name="alpha" >Some Text</child>
   <child id="2"  name="beta" >
      <grandchild id="2.1"  name="beta-alpha" ></grandchild>
      <grandchild id="2.2"  name="beta-beta" ></grandchild>
   </child>
   <pet name="tigger"  type="cat" >
      <data>
         <birthday month="sept"  day="19" ></birthday>
         <food name="Acme Cat Food" ></food>
      </data>
   </pet>
   <pet name="Fido"  type="dog" >
      <description>
         Large dog!
      </description>
      <data>
         <birthday month="feb"  day="3" ></birthday>
         <food name="Acme Dog Food" ></food>
      </data>
   </pet>
   <rogue name="is this real?" >
      <data>
         Hates dogs!
      </data>
   </rogue>
   <child id="3"  name="gamma"  mark="yes" >
      <!-- A comment -->
      <description>
         Likes all animals - especially dogs!
      </description>
      <grandchild id="3.1"  name="gamma-alpha" >
         <[CDATA[ Some non-parsable character data ]]>
      </grandchild>
      <grandchild id="3.2"  name="gamma-beta" ></grandchild>
   </child>
</parent>
</documentRoot>
```

Any help or even just pointing me at the right direction is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitespace and axis misunderstanding are thwarting your attempt.  Use `normalize-space()` and the `descendant-or-self::` axis (`//`) to eliminate the problems...

This XPath

```
//pet[normalize-space(description) = 'Large dog!']
```

will select all `pet` elements whose  `description` child element has a space-normalized string value of `'Large dog!'`.