# find class name by the text that contains its child node

Tags: html, xpath

I am not familiar with both HTML and Xpath so I am not sure whether I specified my question correctly. I use Selenium to scrape some data from certain websites ([link](https://www.praca.egospodarka.pl/oferty-pracy/mazowieckie/technik-serwisu,67186148.html)). I figured out, that for some reason name of the class I interested in differs from page to page, however, this class contains a child node that in its turn contains a button. This button has the same text inside for all pages (`"aplikuj"`, since sometimes appear another button with `"aplikuj"` inside I decided to add some RegEx `"^aplikuj$"`). My question is: **How can I find parent class name knowing that its child node contains a button with particular text inside (`"^aplikuj$"`)**. As on the image below, I am looking for the `"col-box ego-box-tabs-border box-info"` class name (which will differ from page to page).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLs2V.png)

**Updated**: I want to extract text inside of `<p>` tags of `"col-box ego-box-tabs-border box-info"` class

Comment: I'm not familiar with `selenium` (any reason you didn't include its tag?), but if I understand your question correctly, you're probably looking for `//div[p/a="aplikuj"]/p/normalize-space(.//text())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this topic: [XPath to select element based on childs child value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9683054/16106631)

You can select the `div` element that its child node contains a button which have the text 'aplikuj' by this code:

`//div[./p[./a[contains(text(), "aplikuj")]]]`

then, you can extend the code above to get all the text of `p` element in that `div` by this code:

`//div[./p[./a[contains(text(), "aplikuj")]]]/p//text()`